# unable to locate tools.jar. Proper solution?

Tags: ant, jar, java

I have find so many question related to this in SO.

When i type **ant -version** in the command prompt, the following is printed:

*Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\lib tools.jar*

Apache Ant version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014

**Even though it is saying "Unable to locate tools.jar......" it is also printing the version number.**

*All the other solutions didn't work EXCEPT copying the **tools.jar** from:*

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib** and paste it in

**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib**

After this, when i typed **ant -version**, only  *Apache Ant version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014* is diplayed.

Is this solution recommeded?

**FYI:**

Before installing jdk 1.8, I had jdk 1.7 and jre 1.8 already installed separately. Now I have all the three inside the same folder *C:\Program Files\Java*.

In *Environment variable->System variables* , I have defined:

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31;

ANT_HOME: *ant path*

And in the **PATH** included  *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;* 
and ***ant bin path*** also.

Comment: does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` show what you expect it to show ? And can you run `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java` ? Is there an entry in the PATH that includes the JRE bin path before the JDK bin path ?

Comment: @nos no the is no jre path included in PATH

Answer (score 1):

By setting the following Environmental variables as below, my issue was resolved:

In *Environment variable->User variables* , I have defined:

ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4

In *Environment variable->System variables* , I have defined:
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31;

And in the **Path** added the following things:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;

**In my case I was trying some ant script with adb and svn and I don't know whether they were related or not. Because my ADT bundle was in Desktop, so I had to put it inside C drive.**

**In order to work properly I had to setup my environmental variables with following extra paths:**

In *Environment variable->User variables* , I have defined:

SVN_PATH : C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN

ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows\sdk

Inside *Environment variable->System variables* :

in the **Path** added the following paths:

C:\ProgramFiles\TortoiseSVN\bin;

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platform-tools;

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools;

%ANDRIOD_HOME%\platform-tools;

%ANDRIOD_HOME%\tools;

%SVN_PATH%\bin;

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the PATH variable contains only one Java path?
This may be linked to java defined twice on your PATH (with the secon being JRE location).

I had exaclty the same problem in eclipse (which should look for JDK rather than JRE), and the solution was to just manually configure java location in eclipse.

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME contains only one path  and the PATH also contains only the java_home path with bin as written in the question

Comment: before it contains the jre bin path also, but i have deleted. And restarted the system also

Comment: It seems to me like java path is set to JRE instead of JDK in some place which we didn't think of, otherwise it would have to work.

BTW, I cannot run JAVA_HOME either, I think it's normal for every commad including C:\Program Files at the begining (because of the whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

It's a very easy proccess

Copy tools.jar from JDK lib folder & paste it in JRE lib folder .....Just Make sure JDK & JRE installed on your C drive and point their paths in Environment settings.

Once it is done. Open Command Prompt

Type ant -v

If You get below messages then ANT is installed successfully

c:>ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017

I hope it will help.

Thanks,

Priya Gupta